# Can't set border to QDockWidget from external QSS stylesheet file

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qdockwidget

I want to add borders to a `QDockWidget` using an external `QSS` file.

This is what I have:

[image: QDockWidget without borders]

And this is what I want:

[image]

I've tried using:

```
QDockWidget {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

but it doesn't work at all;

If I am using the designer by right clicking on the `QDockWidget` and choosing `Change stylesheet` and I use `border: 5px solid red;` inside the dialog everything works fine.
But I want to use an external `QSS` file.

Is it possible to attach a `QSS` file to my widget and border it as wanted?

Comment: Insert a `QWidget` or a `QFrame` inside your dock and customize it

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a workaround? I would like to apply the stylesheet on an already developed application. I can't change the application's layout.

Comment: It is not a workaround. It is standard way. You are trying to customize platform-specific things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
QDockWidget > QWidget {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Good luck!